# Can't add a HOME email has been specified yet to an existing ANDROID contacs

Tags: android, contacts

I have a proplem when I make a app "contacts manager" for android.
I have processed creating and deleting a contact with name, and phone
but when I want to add more a home email info to an existing contacts but can't do that.

here my code:

ArrayList ops = new ArrayList(); 
            String selectName = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? ";
            String[] NameArgs = new String[]{strId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

```
        String selectPhone = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? ";
        String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{strId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        String selectEmail = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? ";
        String[] emailArgs = new String[]{strId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        String selectPostAdd = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE + "= ? ";
        String[] postAddArgs = new String[]{strId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)};

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(selectName, NameArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, updContact_name.getText().toString())
                .build()); 
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, updContact_phone.getText().toString())
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(selectEmail, emailArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, updContact_textMail.getText().toString())
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());          
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(selectPostAdd, postAddArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DATA, updContact_textPostAdd.getText().toString())
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                .build());
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

this code is available for update a contacts but an Item Info(here is email, StructruedPostal) has been created once. but when I create it with contacts app of android with only name, number (don't touch email, structuedPostal) and save, I don't update it in my android app.

somebody have experience about this pls help me! tks

sorry about my grammar english! It have more mistake and wrong grammar. :(. Tks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating will not insert field which doesn't exist, so follow these steps.

1. First query for the raw Contact Id of your Contact.
2. use new Insert method to insert data that has not been inserted to the contact previously when created (in the oppt case newUpdate() will work fine).

A piece of code goes like this

```
String[] params = new String[] {"Give your Contact"};// you need query and get this too.
String[] proj =  {ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,proj, 
                ContactsContract.Data._ID +"= ?", params, null);
long rawContactId = -1;

while(c.moveToNext()){
    rawContactId = c.getLong(0);
}
c.close();
```

After getting those values,

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, data.getEmail2Address())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());
```

Comment: when you open default contacts manager on virtual machine and add a contacts with only name and phone number and save it. When I debug to this line by my contacts my app contacts manager.           c.moveToNext() is false and rawContactId = c.getLong(0) dont have value.